# Can't Access Network Resources Over VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, active-directory

I am using Windows Server 2012 and RRAS to setup a VPN connection to a client. I have two servers on an Active Directory domain.

- DC01 (this hosts the VPN and Active Directory Domain Controller)
- QA01

When I connect to the VPN server hosted on DC01, I am able to resolve DC01 and access all the network resources on DC01.

I am not able to access any network resources for QA01 from the computer with the VPN client however.

One note, they are both on different IP ranges.

- DC01 is say 173.1.1.1
- QA01 is 68.1.1.1

Also, if I remote desktop into either server, I am able to access either computers network resources without a problem.

Default gateway is checked for the VPN connection and the correct DNS server is being used when connected to the VPN. I see that the QA01 IP address is being returned via NSLookup, however I am not able to access any network resources for QA01.

I have also already disabled the firewalls to see if this resolved the issue but it didn't.

Finally, I use RRAS to assign a static IP to the client. In this case, that IP is 10.1.0.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Which IP address do you get when you connect to the VPN on DC01? It is likely you have a separate (and not fully routed) subnet the VPN connections are put on.

Comment: I actually assign a static IP on the internal range. 10.1.0.1 I should have mentioned that, will edit the original question.